Should this bare minimum TRIAC circuit light the bulb?
In trying to build a multi-channel, optoisolated, TRIAC based, switch module, I could not even get one channel to function properly.
Trying to isolate the problem, I've reduced the circuit to this bare minimum, that I thought should work.
I've tried BT137-800, BTA08-600B, BTA16-600B, BT136-600 that I had laying arround.
None work in this configuration. Are they all broken (some were new)?
Please help me understand, what obvious problem am I missing?


I am assuming pin 2 is your gate and you need to pull the gate voltage above or below the voltage on pin 1 to turn the TRIAC on.  But your gate voltage is always equal to the pin 1 voltage unless current is already flowing.  How would the TRIAC turn on?

@Tony Wouldn't R1 drop some of that voltage?

@TimWilliams It does indeed. I had already added it to an answer myself.

(Kind of a quirk: voting to close as duplicate generates that comment automatically.)

That is a "static switch" circuit. To turn the triac on you would connect the gate to MT2, not MT1 (as you have it), through the resistor.
The triac will turn off at each zero crossing and will turn on again somewhat after the zero crossing, causing a bit of EMI. The voltage across the triac has  to build up to where the current through the resistor is equal to the trigger current. For example, if the trigger current is +/-20mA in quadrants I and III and the gate voltage at trigger is +/-1V then it will switch on when the voltage across the triac is around +/-10.4V. Usually the bulb (even hot) will be much less resistance than 470Ω so that will be approximately the mains voltage at trigger.
Note that your "1/4-W" resistor could (worst case) see peak mains voltage of around than 325V briefly (112W peak dissipation) so it should able to withstand that voltage and peak power. Otherwise it could fail randomly depending on where in the AC cycle it is turned on.

Thank you for the additional info and warnings. Much appreciated.

This https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/394020/361107 answer to a similar question answered my problem as well. I had the T1 and T2 TRIAC terminals reversed. I was connecting the gate, through R1, to T1 while I should have been connecting it to T2. It now works fine.
